# Change OpenVPN config

Tags: openvpn

I am on `Win10` and using `openvpn` via `openvpn-gui` running out of startup (and not as a service for some reason, if it makes difference). The software is installed in *D:\soft\openvpn* and I know that it uses config (*.ovpn + certs) that are in *D:\some\other\dir*. What I can't find is where to change from that config to another. I tried to open the properties on the startup link to openvpn-gui but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the readme-file](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn-gui/blob/master/README.rst#adding-an-openvpn-configuration-file) on Github, OpenVPN-GUI looks for global and user `.ovpn`-files. 
The default location is a directory called `config` in the installation folder. User configurarion files are kept in your home folder (`%USERPROFILE%\OpenVPN\config`).

You can see the path `openvpn-gui` uses in the registry under`HKLM\SOFTWaRE\OpenVPN-GUI`

More details can be found in [this OpenVPN Community wiki article](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN-GUI).

Answer (score 0):

If there is only on config in the configuration directory eg. "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config" and when you right-click in the taskbar on openvpn and select Connect you get that one profile.

To change the profile that connects when only one is present go in to the config-directory and change the config in there, then restart the application.